# How to add EventListeners with JavaScript, to a varying number of elements the server returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, listener

How can i add EventListeners with JQuery/JavaScript to a varying number of elements the server returns?

The server uses a Mustache-Template engine to generate the elements:

```
...
{{#resource.recordEntries}}
<form action="http://x/{{entryId}}/" method="post">
    <textarea id="inputArea{{entryId}}" class="inputArea">{{description}}</textarea>
    <button id="saveEntry{{entryId}}" class="saveEntry" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
{{/resource.recordEntries}}
...
```

For example here it returns 2 textareas and 2 buttons:

```
<textarea id="inputArea1" class="inputArea">Desciription Area1</textarea>
<button id="saveEntry1" class="saveEntry" type="submit">Save Area1</button>

<textarea id="inputArea2" class="inputArea">Desciription Area2</textarea>
<button id="saveEntry2" class="saveEntry" type="submit">Save Area2</button>
```

The critical part is the registration of the EventListeners. I could do it in a static way like this for every element, but i don't know how many elements the server returns:

```
$("button[id=saveEntry1]").css({"display": "none"});
document.getElementById("inputArea1").addEventListener("input", function() {
    $("button[id=saveEntry1]").css({"display": "block"});
}, false);
document.getElementById("saveEntry1").addEventListener('click', function() {
  $("button[id=saveEntry1]").css({"display": "none"});  
}, false);
```

In this [code example](http://jsfiddle.net/martin_martin/bfkwhbsy/) I register EventListeners to 3 textareas and buttons in a static way. 
What changes are necessary, that the code works more dynamic? So that it still works even if the server returns more than 3 elements.

Thanks a lot!
-martin.martin

Comment: Hey @martin.martin. Fix the link to the code, and post the critical parts in the question. This will help other people to help you, and will prevent more trigger happy people from down voting you. Also include some examples of what you tried.

Comment: How are these elements created? I mean, are they inserted in the DOM after an AJAX call or the html is created dynamically and then served to the requester?

Comment: @OriDrori: Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @Pablo: I added the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the classes and bind the event to all the elements with that class. 
Then you do your changes to the pressed element with `$(this)`.

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
// Add listener for first textarea and button  
    $(".saveEntry").hide();
    $(".inputArea").on("input", function() {
     $(this).next(".saveEntry").show();
    })
    $(".saveEntry").on("click", function () {
     $(this).hide();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="inputArea1" class="inputArea">Desciription Area1</textarea>
<button id="saveEntry1" class="saveEntry" type="submit">Save Area1</button>

<textarea id="inputArea2" class="inputArea">Desciription Area2</textarea>
<button id="saveEntry2" class="saveEntry" type="submit">Save Area2</button>

<textarea id="inputArea3" class="inputArea">Desciription Area3</textarea>
<button id="saveEntry3" class="saveEntry" type="submit">Save Area3</button>

<p> The number of textareas and buttons varies, depending on what the server returns. How can i register the listeners dynamically to all generated elements?</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Joel Almeida. In my real code, every button and textarea is sourounded by a <div>. http://jsfiddle.net/martin_martin/5jc21jsm/ Could you help me with the selectors? There it doesn't work.

Comment: @martin.martin can't you place the textarea and the button inside the same div?

Comment: i managed it like that: $(this).parent().next().children(".saveEntry").show(); Thanks again, you helped me a lot to make it work. But I'm still wondering if there is another solution which is not relatated to the HTML structure and related to the ID of the textareas and buttons.

Comment: There is another way. You can use `$(this).attr('id')` and get the number of that 2, for example. Then you do `$('#saveSearch' + theNumber)`. Something along those lines